# puppetserver ca commands fail connecting to https://puppet:8140 when using SRV record solution

Tags: puppet, ca, srv

I use SRV solution in my puppet architecture. When trying to setup a new puppet master and CA and view my certificates I get this error:

```
puppetserver ca list --all
Fatal error when running action 'list'
  Error: Failed connecting to https://puppet:8140/puppet-ca/v1/certificate_statuses/any_key
  Root cause: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: No address associated with hostname)
```

My puppet.conf file has the following configuration:

```
   use_srv_records = true
   srv_domain = mypuppetrecord.com
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to find the solution here. I needed to add to my `/etc/hosts` file the following:

xxx.xx.xx.xx (IP of the host)  puppet